# Unable to keep elements preserved in a vector after a boolean "do while" loop

Tags: arrays, loops, vector, boolean, element

I am in a process of making a bitcoin managing program for an intro CS class and here are my objectives (only mentioned ones that I need in this context): I have managed to complete the following objectives.
My program has 4 menu options stored in class `menu`. The user can choose from the following:

1. Find current Bitcoin value in USD
2. Buy/sell Bitcoin
3. Print current balance
4. **Print history of transactions**

Let's say the user selections option 2 and inputs how much user wants to sell or buy. The program will so far do the following:

> - calculates how much the bitcoin is worth (randomly generated between 5k to 7k per 1 BTC)
> - retrieves how much user wants to buy in USD
> - converts the value of USD to BTC in class `wallet` and retrieves the current date of the transaction from class `getLive`.
> - Then the two values are converted into type `string` and is passed onto function `void bitcoinHistory(string bitcoinAmnt, string date)`

Currently I am having trouble with the following step:

> - **... and storing the two strings in the class called `ledger` and printing out the transaction history. The user can make as many as transactions as one may desire.**

So far, I've tried creating a vector and I tried using `push_back.()` every time the function is called.

```
class ledger        // the log of all transactions
                    //1) It will store the transaction strings just so we have
                    //a record of the buy sell commands
                    //2) It will be able to print out the transaction history if requested

{
      public:
        vector<string> bitcoin;

        void bitcoinHistory(string bitcoinAmnt, string date)        
        {                                                          
            string btc, time;
            btc = bitcoinAmnt;
            time = date;

            bitcoin.push_back(btc + "BTC on " + time);

            for (unsigned int x = 0; x < bitcoin.size(); x++)
            {

                cout << bitcoin[x] << endl;

            }
            repeat = true;                          \\ boolean returns the user back to main menu
```

A sample result from `cout << bitcoin[x]` I am successfully able to get: `0.035349BTC on Wed Mar 25 01:44:02 2020`

However, once the program is looped, the previous transactions don't seem to save and the element seems to be replaced with the newer transaction data. Despite multiple transactions, the `bitcoin.size()` seems to be resetting, and I only see an output of a single transaction history only. I am not able to figure out why. If you'd like to see more part of the code, please let me know. Thank you.